# how to use loop to insert data with last day of each month in mysql?

Tags: mysql

**Goal**

I have some dates. These dates are the last day of each month.

```
date in 
(
'2019-12-31',
'2020-01-31',
'2020-02-29',
'2020-03-31',
'2020-04-30',
'2020-05-31',
'2020-06-30',
'2020-07-31','2020-08-31','2020-09-30','2020-10-31','2020-11-30',
'2020-12-31','2021-01-31','2021-02-28','2021-03-31')
```

I want to insert data for these dates using loop as below

```
SET num = 0;
SET d='2021-02-28';
set @count=datediff('2019-12-31','2021-03-31')+1;

while 
   num <=@count DO
   insert insert_table
   select * from original_table a where date=d;
   set d=date_sub(d, interval 1 day);
   set num = num + 1;
END WHILE;
```

I don't know how to judge which the date is the last day of month.

**mysql version: 5.5**

Comment: explain what original_table has to do with this and what data is in it?  and how does your list of dates (which already are end of month dates) fit in with needing to judge which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to find the last day for specified `year` and `month` on your MySQL version then you may use

```sql
CONCAT_WS('-', @year, @month, 1) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If you need to check if specified `date` is the last day of the month then you may check

```
DAY(@date + INTERVAL 1 DAY) = 1
```